# mysql - insert only unique data from other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables and I want to insert data from one table to another based on a condition:

table 1:

```
user_id,
agency_user_id,
```

Output from table 1:

```
user_id   agency_user_id
330       20 
330       21
239       10
...       ..
239       10
239       12
239       9
```

table 2:
    has the same plus some other columns that I don't need at the moment...

Once a user is logged in he has 2 dropdown menus, in one I am listing user_id (not the id but info based on id) and in the other agency_user_id...

So the problem is that I don't want to have 2 times:

```
239 10
239 10
```

in table 2... I want only once (unique)...
Here is the query that I used and it doesn't work as I want it:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(`user_id`,`agency_user_id`)
 SELECT `user_id`,`agency_user_id`
FROM table2
WHERE `user_id` AND `agency_user_id` NOT IN (
SELECT `user_id`
 FROM table1
);
```

and now when I check there are duplicate entries in table2...
I know that I am doing something wrong in that WHERE ...  NOT IN part...

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I tried this as well:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(`user_id`,`agency_user_id`)
 SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`,`agency_user_id`
FROM table2
WHERE `user_id` AND `agency_user_id` NOT IN (
SELECT `user_id`
 FROM table1
);
```

Not working...

Current output from table 2

```
  user_id    agency_user_id
   330         20             => ok
   330         21             => ok
   239         10             => ok
   239         10             => not ok
   239         12             => ok
   239         9              => ok
```

and so on...

Comment: You should not insert `created_at` and `updated_at` from one table to another.
Did you try DISTINCT ?

Comment: thanks for suggestion but I need that... yes I did but I still get duplicate entries...

Comment: Or try INSERT IGNORE (...) and primary key the columns

Comment: Is this part correct?

`WHERE user_id AND agency_user_id NOT IN (
SELECT user_id
FROM table1
);`

You are connecting agency_user_id with user_id which doesn't make sense

Comment: add a `GROUP BY` then. DISTINCT doesn't always work. *"Once a user is logged in he has 2 dropdown menus"* - So where's the HTML for all this then? How do the people know if that isn't failing?

Comment: I don't get why you are inserting in `table2` from `table2`. that's going to give you duplicates if the data isn't in `Table1` but is in `Table2`. If you want distinct values that are not already in `Table2` then you should be pulling them from `Table1` where they don't exist in `Table2`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is `DISTINCT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(`user_id`,`agency_user_id`)
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`,`agency_user_id`
FROM table2
WHERE `user_id` NOT IN (
SELECT `user_id`
FROM table1
) AND `agency_user_id` NOT IN (
SELECT `user_id`
FROM table1
);
```

where I removed `created_at` and `updated_at` to avoid duplicates and fixed the `NOT IN` to apply to both `user_id` and `agency_user_id`.

Comment: Is this part correct?

`WHERE user_id AND agency_user_id NOT IN (
SELECT user_id
FROM table1
);`

You are connecting agency_user_id with user_id which doesn't make sense

Comment: My guess would be then that you have `created_at` and/or `updated_at` different for different entries with the same `user_id` and `agency_user_id`. Do you need those? They aren't specified in your desired output...

Comment: Now I have less rows added but still there is duplicate ones... also please check edit

Comment: @Krishnakumar I got nothing, 0 rows affected, 0 errors

Comment: @Krishnakumar Even after changing first FROM table2 => table1 and last select replacing `user_id` with `agency_user_id`

Comment: @Morpheus Did you try using the temp table solution I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a temporary table:

Like the below example:

```
select * from TABLE1;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 | 2    |
|    3 | 4    |
|    1 | 2    |
|    4 | 5    |
+------+------+
```

As you can see

```
1 2
1 2
```

are repeated

create a temp table:

```
create temporary table temp1 (a text, b text, c text);
```

INSERT into this:

```
insert into temp1 select a,b,count(*) from TABLE1 group by a,b;


select * from temp1;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    | 1    |
| 4    | 5    | 1    |
+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally

```
insert into table2 (a ,b) select a,b from temp;

select * from table2;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
| 1    | 2    |
| 3    | 4    |
| 4    | 5    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Helped me once!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(`user_id`,`agency_user_id`)
    SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`,`agency_user_id`
    FROM table1
    WHERE `user_id` + `-` + `agency_user_id` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` + `-` + `agency_user_id` FROM table2);
```

This will select distinct values from `Table1` that are not already in `Table2`.

The way that you have your `insert` it is pulling all `user_id`'s from `Table2` that are not in `Table1`. so if you ahve `user_id`'s that are in `Table2` that are not in `Table1` you will get duplicates.